# Unexpected behaviour when running mocha with `npm test`

Tags: npm, mocha.js

Mocha runs a different amount of unit tests with two seemingly equal commands. When I run mocha with `npm test` I get the following output:

```
> xxx-yyy@1.0.0-alpha.4 test /Users/xxx/repos/some-path
> rm -rf ./.unit-test-build/ && tsc && mocha ./.unit-test-build/**/*.spec.js --reporter progress


  [▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬]

  35 passing (78ms)
```

The thing is; I have more than 35 unit tests in this project. The test command is defined like this in `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "rm -rf ./.unit-test-build/ && tsc && mocha ./.unit-test-build/**/*.spec.js --reporter progress",
  }
}
```

**Now here's the strange part**. When I copy the above command and paste it into a terminal, I get the following output:

`$ rm -rf ./.unit-test-build/ && tsc && mocha ./.unit-test-build/**/*.spec.js --reporter progress`

```
  [▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬]

  123 passing (1s)
```

This is expected behaviour, 123 unit test are passing.

Why does mocha run 35 tests instead of 123 when I use `npm test`? How can I fix this?

I am using node `v7.6.0`, npm `4.1.2` and mocha `3.2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267352/1309907).

You need to put `'` around the glob pattern, like this:

```
                                           ⬇                              ⬇
rm -rf ./.unit-test-build/ && tsc && mocha './.unit-test-build/**/*.spec.js' --reporter progress
```